# Вырезание одной фигуры из другой

Tags: java, libgdx

**Кратко:** из одной геометрической фигуры необходимо вырезать другую геометрическую фигуру так, чтобы нарисованные ранее изображения остались прежними.

[image: Рисунок]

**Подробно:** используя libgdx и ShapeDrawer ([ссылка на github](https://github.com/earlygrey/shapedrawer)), пытаюсь нарисовать некую геометрию.

```java
    SpriteBatch batch;
    ... // Инициализация SpriteBatch и тому подобное
    ShapeDrawer drawer = new ShapeDrawer(batch, region);
    ...
    batch.begin()
    ... // Здесь идёт отрисовка другой графики (на рисунке выше - "зелёный треугольник")
    drawer.filledCircle(0, 0, 100); // "Красный круг" на рисунке
    ...
    batch.end()
```

Необходимо из нарисованного круга (или сектора) вырезать следующую фигуру:

```java
    ... // Здесь отрисовка "красного круга"
    drawer.filledRectangle(25,25, 500, 400); // "Пунктирный прямоугольник" на рисунке
    ... // Здесь batch.end()
```

Начал копать в сторону блендинга OpenGL. Нашёл полезный сайтик, по нему определил необходимые (по моему мнению настройки). Получилось так:

```java
    ...
    batch.begin()
    ... // Здесь идёт отрисовка другой графики (на рисунке выше - "зелёный треугольник")
    drawer.filledCircle(0, 0, 100); // "Красный круг" на рисунке

    drawer.getBatch().enableBlending();
    drawer.getBatch().setBlendFunction(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    drawer.filledRectangle(25,25, 500, 400); // "Пунктирный прямоугольник" на рисунке
    drawer.getBatch().disableBlending();
    ...
    batch.end()
```

Проблема в том, что при таком подходе "зелёный треугольник" так же обрезается, чего не хотелось бы допустить. Да, проблема полностью исчезает, если поменять порядок отрисовки: сперва "красный круг", затем вырезать его с помощью "пунктирного прямоугольника", а после "зелёный треугольник". Тем не менее мне **важно сохранить порядок** "слоёв": "красный круг" должен перекрывать "зелёный треугольник" (или, по крайней мере, не перекрываться им).

Есть ли способ это сделать без применения велосипедов?

*P.s. Также было бы интересно узнать, можно ли как-то "сохранить" рисуемое изображение (всё, что находится между batch.begin() и batch.end(), чтобы, например, не пересчитывать какие-то наложение и т.п.*

---

По совету @Master Flomaster попробовал использовать FrameBuffer, однако столкнулся с проблемой наложения и, собственно, вырезания текстуры. В данный момент основные действующие объекты определены так (грубо говоря):

```java
public class GameScreen{
  ShapeDrawer drawer;
  FrameBuffer fbo;

  public GameScreen(){
    fbo = new FrameBuffer(...);
    drawer = new ShapeDrawer(batch, region); // Здесь batch - одно из полей супер-класса
  }
...
  public void render(){
    batch.begin();
    ... // Отрисовка мира
    fbo.begin();

    ... // Вот здесь располагается код из случая 1 и случая 2 (см. ниже)

    fbo.end();
    batch.end();
  }
}
```

**Случай 1:** я пытаюсь использовать batch drawer-а. В таком случае всё, что находится перед командой `drawer.getBatch().disableBlending();` не отрисовывается вообще.
[image: Использование drawer]

```java
// Код случая 1
        fbo.begin();
        drawer.setColor(0.85f,0.1f,0.1f,1f);
        drawer.sector(0,0,(float) window_w/10,0, (float) (3.15/2));
//Разница только в коде ниже
        drawer.getBatch().enableBlending();
        drawer.getBatch().setBlendFunction(GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ZERO);

        drawer.setColor(0f,0f,0f,1f);
        drawer.filledRectangle(25,25, 500, 400);

        drawer.getBatch().disableBlending();
//Разница только в коде выше
        drawer.setColor(0.1f,0.35f,0.85f,1f);
        drawer.sector(window_w,0,(float) window_w/10,(float) (3.14/2), 3.15f);
        drawer.setColor(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f, 1f);
        drawer.rectangle(200, 0, 400, 50);
        fbo.end();
```

**Случай 2:** я пытаюсь использовать команды Gdx.gl.*** . В таком случае наложение не работает совершенно.
[image: Использование OpenGL]

```java
// Код случая 2
        fbo.begin();
        drawer.setColor(0.85f,0.1f,0.1f,1f);
        drawer.sector(0,0,(float) window_w/10,0, (float) (3.15/2));
//Разница только в коде ниже
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        drawer.setColor(0f,0f,0f,1f);
        drawer.filledRectangle(25,25, 500, 400);

        Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL_BLEND);
//Разница только в коде выше
        drawer.setColor(0.1f,0.35f,0.85f,1f);
        drawer.sector(window_w,0,(float) window_w/10,(float) (3.14/2), 3.15f);
        drawer.setColor(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f, 1f);
        drawer.rectangle(200, 0, 400, 50);
        fbo.end();
```

В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: В этой вашей графической библиотеке есть понятие регионов отсечения (clipping) и возможность комбинировать регионы?

Comment: @MBo, по идее "эта моя графическая библиотека" является надстройкой над OpenGL, и если clipping есть там, то возможно он есть и тут. Попробую поискать подобное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно отрендерить круг с прямоугольником во фрейм буффер. А потом наложить полученый результат на треугольник.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать, есть ли в libgdx что-то уже реализованное или придётся лезть в OpenGL?

Comment: Конечно есть https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html. И пример можно тут посмотреть https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434236/libgdx-framebuffer.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос с уже следующей возникшей проблемой при этом способе. Есть мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: Сложно так сразу сказать. Что будет если убрать все строчки с включением/отключением блендинга?

Comment: Если закомментировать оба вариант, то происходит ситуация, аналогичная случаю 2 из вопроса.

Comment: Оуф, прошу прощения. Моя невнимательность завела меня в тупик. Я совершенно упустил из виду тот факт, что в предлагаемом вами выше вопросе создавали Sprite и отрисовывали его.

Comment: Порядок вызыва должен быть другой. Сначала fbo.begin() потом batch.begin() и когда будет закончен рендеринг во фрейм буфер надо достать текстуру fbo.getColorBufferTexture() и рендерить ее. Если ничего не изменится то отложим вопрос до завтра.